# How to define Current Year in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to do a very easy SAS calculation such as Age=current_year- birth_year.

How do I set current year? I tried current_year=2018; but SAS does not like this answer?

I am needing to know how to set current year to 2018.

```
data merged_bike;
  merge all_clean_data (in=a) boroughs(in=b);
  by station_id;
  if a and b; 
run; 
Current_year =2018; 
Age= Current_year - birth_year; 
if Age <29 then age_group ='0-29'; 
else if Age > 30 and age<40 then age_group= '30-39'; 
else if Age>40 and age<50 then age_group='40-49'; 
else if Age>50 and age<60 then age_group='50-59'; 
else if Age>60 and age<70 then age_group='60-69'; 
run;
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code you tried?

Comment: Hi Tom,  the code was: current_year=2018; Age= current_year - birth_year;

Comment: How did you create birth_year? Where is the data statement? set statement? input statement?

Comment: Hi Tom, That is all I did. I am pretty new with this was I supposed to create the current_year statement differently?

Comment: HI Tom, this is the code I am trying to run. 
    data merged_bike;
    merge all_clean_data (in=a) boroughs(in=b);
    by station_id;
    if a and b;
    run;
    Current_year =2018;
    Age= Current_year - birth_year;
    if Age <29 then age_group ='0-29';
    else if Age > 30 and age<40 then age_group= '30-39';
    else if Age>40 and age<50 then age_group='40-49';
    else if Age>50 and age<60 then age_group='50-59';
    else if Age>60 and age<70 then age_group='60-69';
    run;

Comment: year is not a number. if you do year calculation that way you will miss the whole concept of dates and leap year. You have take whole date into consideration for calculating age not just the year. please look into this paper for various ways of calculating date. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/060-30.pdf

Comment: @Kiran In more recent versions of SAS you can (finally) make use of the `intck()` function to calculate anniversaries (such as age).  Look at the `continuous` option here:  http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: you are right @robert. great point. Just wanted OP to know calculation of date does not mean you subtract from one number to another.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have assignment statements outside of a data step. Remove the extra `run;` statement that is ending the data step definition too soon.

Or create a second data step to read the data back in and run your age calculations.

If you want today's year you can use the `date()` function (or its alias `today()`) and then use the `year()` function to extract the year.

```
current_year = year(date());
```